# Как выровнять содержимое блока div по противоположным его краям?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Есть блок HTML:

```
<div class="heading">
  <span class="img-icon"><img src="icon.svg"></span>
  <p class="title">Заголовок</p>
</div>
```

Как выровнять `<span>` по левому краю блока `<div>`, а `<p>` по правому? Т.е. чтобы они расположились в противоположных концах родительского блока `<div>` c помощью CSS без JavaScript?

Comment: Еще бы ответы принимали пользователи, было бы вообще круто ))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

еще вариант с `float`:

```css
.heading {overflow: hidden;}

.heading span {display:block; float:left;}

.heading .title {float:right;}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <span class="img-icon"><img src="icon.svg"></span>
  <p class="title">Заголовок</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Так-же отличный вариант, ведь flex не всегда подходит 

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич у HamSter в примере нету flex

Comment: @ПавелИгоревич, точнее не всеми браузерами flex поддерживается))) но весьма удобен в использовании

Answer (score 3):

```css
.heading{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <span class="img-icon"><img src="icon.svg"></span>
  <p class="title">Заголовок</p>
</div>
```